# after installing ubuntu-desktop on kubuntu 20.10 at asks for permission repeatedly

Tags: permissions, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 20.10 on my laptop and wanted to try Ubuntu. Then instaled ubuntu-desktop package and switched the session to ubuntu.
Now there is an annoying message appears and asks for permission for every single thing that I believe should not be needed and asks it again and again...

**For example:**

- System policy prevents wifi scans
- System policy prevents control of network connections

**And these one at startup:**

- Authentication is required to create a color profile
- Authentication is required to create a color profile managed device
- ...

And the most weird thing is that every-time I want to shut down, this message appears:

- other users are loggin in

**And shows my user as the other user!!!**

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem which started this week.  Based on what I have done to my system the past week, I just undid the one thing that was suspect and the problem appears to have been resolved.

I had installed the `chrome-remote-desktop` package to allow remote desktop access via Chrome.  That was the beginning of my problems.  Once I uninstalled that and I restarted, the problem (so far) has disappeared...

I hope this helps!  A better solution would be to fix this problem while having `chrome-remote-desktop` working, but I never got it working anyway...  So, for me, removing it was easier.

Hope this helps!